# Localize a list's Custom EditForm.aspx in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, localization, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

(I'm a starter in the sharepoint world)

See screenshot below. In the default EditForm.aspx, the title is translated automatically.
But this custom editform is obviously always displayed with English labels.

The Editform was created by just doing "add form" in the List Properties screen in SPD.

**What do I need to get the same translation as in the default editform?**

[alt text http://thomasstock.net/translatesp.jpg](http://thomasstock.net/translatesp.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$Resources:core,Title;`

See resource keys in `SharePointRoot\Resources\core.resx` (For SP2007 it's there, but see if its there in 2010).